# Проблема с кодировкой: все записи кроме латиницы и цифр сохраняются кракозябрами

Tags: кодировка, php

Добрый день. Пытаюсь организовать импорт `CSV` в `MySql` но возникают проблемы с кодировкой. Все записи кроме латиницы и цифр сохраняются кракозябрами. Подскажите как решить проблему? Ниже привожу код.

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","admin","12345") or die('No connection to server');

mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');

mysql_select_db("12345",$connect) or die('No connection to DB!');

$max_file_size = 5; // Максимальный размер файла в МегаБайтах

if($_POST['update']=='ok')

{

    // СТАРТ Загрузка файла на сервер

    if($_FILES["filename"]["size"] > $max_file_size*1024*1024)

    {

        echo 'Максимальный размер файла '.$max_file_size.' Mb!';

        include('file_upload.php');

        exit;

    }

    if(copy($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"],$path.$_FILES["filename"]["name"]))

    {

        echo("Фаил "."<b>".$_FILES["filename"]["name"]."</b>"." Был успешно загружен");

    }

    else

    {

        echo 'Ошибка загрузки';

        include('file_upload.php');

        exit;

    }

    $file = fopen('php://memory', 'w+');

    fwrite($file, iconv('CP1251', 'UTF-8', file_get_contents($_FILES["filename"]["name"])));

    rewind($file);

    mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE `ppppp`"); // Очистка старой таблицы

    $r = 0; // это строки в файле

    while (($row = fgetcsv($file, 40000, ";")) != FALSE)  // $file - имя файла; 1000 - длина; ,(запятая) - это разделитель полей

    {

        $r++;

        if($r == 1) {continue;} // Не дает записать в БД первую строку (бывает так, что первая строка используется для заголовков)

        $ins="INSERT INTO ppppp (w,ww,www,wwww,wwwww) VALUES ('$row[0]', '$row[1]', '$row[2]', '$row[3]', '$row[4]')";

        mysql_query($ins);

        //echo mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error(); // это вывод результата. если че, то можно закоментить

    }

    fclose($file);

}
```

Таблица в `UTF-8` база тоже.

Comment: Всем спасибо отбой тревоги разобрался.

Comment: @alexsis20102, написали бы ответ для порядка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто проворонил один момент за который впринципе мне оч стыдно... не хотел писать. Вообщем база в утф 8 таблица тоже в утф 8. А ячейки были в windows-1251....